# How to add email link to layout xml, Android

Tags: android, email, text, hyperlink, android-alertdialog

I have an xml file I use to show the About AlertDialog in my App.
I was able to have an area of text from a text resource, and an image to the right of the text.
Now I need to add the support email and possible home website address to the text. But I need it to be clickable. So clicking on the email will send an email and clicking on the website will open the browser.
How do I add those linked text?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1" android:orientation="horizontal" android:baselineAligned="true">
    <TextView android:text="@string/AboutString" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="173dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:drawableRight="@drawable/explain"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: The solution I chose:

```
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about, null);
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("somemail@domain.net");
                String Scheme = "mailto:somemail@domain.net";
                Linkify.addLinks((TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.textView1), p, Scheme);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [linkify](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html) your text. Here is an example from that article showing how to add links when a WikiWord is found:

```java
Pattern wikiWordMatcher = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-Z]+[a-z0-9]+[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]+\\b");
String wikiViewURL =    "content://com.google.android.wikinotes.db.wikinotes/wikinotes/";
Linkify.addLinks(noteView, wikiWordMatcher, wikiViewURL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this *shameless plug*: https://github.com/ariefbayu/Clickable-URL-TextView-Example

Basically, you would set your TextView into:

```xml
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="TextView"
  android:clickable="true" />
```

on `onCreate`:

```java
html.append("<a href='lauch.TCActivity://SENDEMAIL?email=mail@example.com&subject=email subject&body=this is email body'>Email</a>");
textView.setClickable(true);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

And process it in TCActivity:

```java
if(data.getHost().equals("SENDEMAIL")){
    Log.i("LOG", "Email:" + data.getQueryParameter("email"));
    Log.i("LOG", "Subject:" + data.getQueryParameter("subject"));
    Log.i("LOG", "Body:" + data.getQueryParameter("body"));
}
```

That's it. You should now get the Idea of what to do next.

See:

- [Send email using Intent.ACTION_SEND](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/03/send-email-using-intentactionsend.html)

Comment: I can add this to the string:
<a href="mailto:somemail@domain.com">somemail@domain.com</a>
But it just colors the email as a link and doesn't do anything when I click it. Maybe if I add clickable = true it will work.
Basically, I don't want to write my own send email dialog, that's pointless. Is there a simple way to invoke the default mailing method for the device?

Comment: inside `if(data.getHost().equals("SENDEMAIL")){}` you would call `Intent.ACTION_SEND` as instructed in the **clue**

Answer (score 1):

This was simple for me (using SDK version 23. Not sure if this property exists in earlier version). Add autoLink="email" in textview and give email id in Strings.xml. This email id comes in blue color as link and it opens us email once clicked. Pls try and let me know.

```
<string name="MailText">Click abc@gmail.com to send us a mail for any query</string>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mailtext"
    android:text="@string/MailText"
    android:autoLink="email"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Android `TextView` has a property called `autoLink` which excepts few parameters and one of them is `email` which will tell the framework to handle any kind of emails in this `textView` as clickable.

Please follow example below:

```xml
<TextView
    ....
    android:text="youremail@gmail.com"
    android:autoLink = "email"
/>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 